# Check if a String is combined with Several Substring in C#

Tags: c#

Lets say I have several short string:

`string[] shortStrings = new string[] {"xxx","yyy","zzz"};`
(this definition can change length on array and on string too, so not a fixed one)

When a given string, I like to check if it combines with the shortStrings ONLY, how?

let say function is like `bool TestStringFromShortStrings(string s)`

then

```
TestStringFromShortStrings("xxxyyyzzz") = true;
TestStringFromShortStrings("xxxyyyxxx") = true;
TestStringFromShortStrings("xxxyyy") = true;
TestStringFromShortStrings("xxxxxx") = true;
TestStringFromShortStrings("xxxxx") = false;
TestStringFromShortStrings("xxxXyyyzzz") = false;
TestStringFromShortStrings("xxx2yyyxxx") = false;
```

Please suggest a memory not tense and relatively fast method.

**[EIDT] What this function for?**

I will personally use this function to test if a string is a combination of a [PINYIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin) ok, some Chinese stuff. Following Chinese are same thing if you cannot read it.

检测一个字符串是否为汉语拼音（例如检测是否拼音域名）
所有的汉语拼音字符串有：

(To detect whether a string is Hanyu Pinyin (e.g. detect the phonetic domain) of the Pinyin string:)

```
Regex PinYin = new Regex(@"^(a|ai|an|ang|ao|ba|bai|ban|bang|bao|bei|ben|beng|bi|bian|biao|bie|bin|bing|bo|bu|ca|cai|can|cang|cao|ce|cen|ceng|cha|chai|chan|chang|chao|che|chen|cheng|chi|chong|chou|chu|chua|chuai|chuan|chuang|chui|chun|chuo|ci|cong|cou|cu|cuan|cui|cun|cuo|da|dai|dan|dang|dao|de|den|dei|deng|di|dia|dian|diao|die|ding|diu|dong|dou|du|duan|dui|dun|duo|e|ei|en|eng|er|fa|fan|fang|fei|fen|feng|fo|fou|fu|ga|gai|gan|gang|gao|ge|gei|gen|geng|gong|gou|gu|gua|guai|guan|guang|gui|gun|guo|ha|hai|han|hang|hao|he|hei|hen|heng|hong|hou|hu|hua|huai|huan|huang|hui|hun|huo|ji|jia|jian|jiang|jiao|jie|jin|jing|jiong|jiu|ju|juan|jue|jun|ka|kai|kan|kang|kao|ke|ken|keng|kong|kou|ku|kua|kuai|kuan|kuang|kui|kun|kuo|la|lai|lan|lang|lao|le|lei|leng|li|lia|lian|liang|liao|lie|lin|ling|liu|long|lou|lu|lv|luan|lue|lve|lun|luo|ma|mai|man|mang|mao|me|mei|men|meng|mi|mian|miao|mie|min|ming|miu|mo|mou|mu|na|nai|nan|nang|nao|ne|nei|nen|neng|ni|nian|niang|niao|nie|nin|ning|niu|nong|nou|nu|nv|nuan|nuo|nun|ou|pa|pai|pan|pang|pao|pei|pen|peng|pi|pian|piao|pie|pin|ping|po|pou|pu|qi|qia|qian|qiang|qiao|qie|qin|qing|qiong|qiu|qu|quan|que|qun|ran|rang|rao|re|ren|reng|ri|rong|rou|ru|ruan|rui|run|ruo|sa|sai|san|sang|sao|se|sen|seng|sha|shai|shan|shang|shao|she|shei|shen|sheng|shi|shou|shu|shua|shuai|shuan|shuang|shui|shun|shuo|si|song|sou|su|suan|sui|sun|suo|ta|tai|tan|tang|tao|te|teng|ti|tian|tiao|tie|ting|tong|tou|tu|tuan|tui|tun|tuo|wa|wai|wan|wang|wei|wen|weng|wo|wu|xi|xia|xian|xiang|xiao|xie|xin|xing|xiong|xiu|xu|xuan|xue|xun|ya|yan|yang|yao|ye|yi|yin|ying|yo|yong|you|yu|yuan|yue|yun|za|zai|zan|zang|zao|ze|zei|zen|zeng|zha|zhai|zhan|zhang|zhao|zhe|zhei|zhen|zheng|zhi|zhong|zhou|zhu|zhua|zhuai|zhuan|zhuang|zhui|zhun|zhuo|zi|zong|zou|zu|zuan|zui|zun|zuo)+$");
```

用下面的正则表达式方法，试过了，最简单而且效果非常好，就是有点慢:(
递归的方式对长字符串比较麻烦，容易内存溢出

(Tried it with the regular expression: it's the most simple and gives very good results, but it's a bit slow. The recursive way on the long string is too much trouble, it's too easy to overflow the stack.)

Comment: What do you mean with »if it combines with the shortStrings ONLY«?

Comment: means only have the shortStrings (one or several, can repeat), and contains nothing else.

Comment: @Joey, the problem is the long string has no space inside, so I have to know where to cut first.

Comment: If I remember my string search algorithms right, I don't think you can do much better with performance than the naive approach.

Comment: (My reasoning for that being that most of the "fast" string search algorithms are based on skipping more than one character in case of a mismatch to search the whole string quickly. In your case you either match at the current index and skip past the whole needle length, or have to try another needle, and if all fail, your entire search fails. So the main optimisation for this sort of thing simply isn't available in your case.)

Comment: @EricYin I added a non-recursive version of my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edit: Simplified this a lot thanks to L.B and millimoose.*

[Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to the rescue!  Using [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx), we get:

```
public static bool TestStringFromShortStrings(string checkText, string[] pieces) {
    // Build the expression.  Ultimate result will be
    // of the form "^(xxx|yyy|zzz)+$".
    var expr = "^(" + 
               String.Join("|", pieces.Select(Regex.Escape)) + 
               ")+$";

    // Check whether the supplied string matches the expression.
    return Regex.IsMatch(checkText, expr);
}
```

This should be able to properly handle cases that have multiple repeated patterns of different lenghts.  E.g. if you the list of possible pieces includes strings `"xxx"` and `"xxxx"`.

Comment: Regex is probably the best way to do this *correctly* for any case anyway. (Not necessarily fast though because of the backtracking.)

Comment: You probably want to use [`Regex.Escape()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) when appending a `piece`.

Comment: It seems overly complex to me, but I think it could work. What's the `Replace` doing there? And your method returns `false` for an empty string. An empty string is always a good match, in my opinion.

Comment: @Virtlink Should have been `Regex.Escape()`.  Fixed.

Comment: All codes forming `expr` can be replaced with a single line `"^(" + String.Join("|", pieces.Select(s=>Regex.Escape(s))) + ")+$"`

Comment: While we're golfing, you don't need the lambda, you can shorten that call to `pieces.Select(Regex.Escape)`

Comment: @millimoose Thanks, chaned.  Well, composing this answer was certainly a good educational experience.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the target string to string builder. For each string in shortstring array, remove all occurences from target. If u end up in zero length string, true else false.

Edit:
This approach is not correct. Please refer to comments. Keeping this answer still here as it may look reasonably correct initially.

Comment: Wouldn't this copy data in the source string around needlessly?

Comment: As an alternative: Do a regex replace of `string.Join("|", shortStrings)` with an empty string.

Comment: sounds a good idea, I can repeatedly remove each short string until cannot remove anymore

Comment: @EricYin This will break if the short strings aren't the same length. E.g. if you match `{"xxx", "xxxx"}` against `"xxxxxxx"`.

Comment: @Ankush just have a thought, remove may not work. e.g. `abc` removes `b` becomes `ac`, may just match `ac` that original string not contains

Comment: @millimoose yepp, just thought that too.

Answer (score 2):

You could compare the start of the input string with each of the short strings. As soon as you have a match, you take the rest of the string and repeat. As soon as you have no more string left, you're done. For example:

```
string[] shortStrings = new string[] { "xxx", "yyy", "zzz" };

bool Test(string input)
{
    if (input.Length == 0)
        return true;

    foreach (string shortStr in shortStrings)
    {
        if (input.StartsWith(shortStr))
        {
            if (Test(input.Substring(shortStr.Length)))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You might optimize this by removing the recursion, or by sorting the short strings and do a binary instead of a linear search.

---

Here is a non-recursive version, that uses a `Stack` object instead. No chance of getting a `StackOverflowException`:

```
string[] shortStrings = new string[] { "xxx", "yyy", "zzz" };

bool Test(string input)
{
    Stack<string> stack = new Stack<string>();
    stack.Push(input);

    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        string str = stack.Pop();
        if (str.Length == 0)
            return true;
        foreach (string shortStr in shortStrings)
        {
            if (str.StartsWith(shortStr))
                stack.Push(str.Substring(shortStr.Length));
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This gonna work, just might stock overflow for long string, will try. But for the code, I believe it is what I am looking for

Comment: This has the same problem as Ankush's answer; it won't work if you match {"xxx", "xxxx"} against "xxxxxxx" - you'd have to backtrack for that.

Comment: @millimoose holly moose, you really have a good eye and fast thinking on chaos

Comment: @millimoose You are not correct. I just tested it and it works for your example. It backtracks naturally by recursion.

Comment: @Virtlink Ah. My bad, I didn't notice your approach is recursive.